# How to create websocket separate channel?

Tags: java, html, websocket

Let's say I want to create a chatroom with one public room and dynamically created private rooms by any user who would want to.

How does Websocket be able to support the creation of private channels for these private rooms ?

pusher, jwebsocket for example seem to have this concept. But what if I want to use more standard server like Jetty ?

Comment: Yes but this exercice is a pretext for me learning advanced websocket :)

Comment: Hello, I´m stuck trying to do exactly the same with websocket-rails, did you finally find a way to create dinamically the channels?

Answer (score 1):

This has very little to do with WebSockets (which is a transport protocol). The server/application can do whatever it wants with browser connections.

In the very specific case of chat applications, the broadcast domains (i.e. channel/room) for various users (not connections) is determined by the application. Each WebSocket connection would generally be associated with a authenticated user (but users may have more than one WebSocket connection). The application (server) would keep track of which users are in which channels/rooms and broadcast messages accordingly (by matching users in that room to the connections 'owned' by those users).